# ToUri() not convert all extra in intent (parcelable, serializable, byte[]..)

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

When i add a array of byte in my intent like this :

> Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN" );
>
> Bundle param = new Bundle();
>
> ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>
> bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
>
> param.putByteArray("image",bs.toByteArray());
>
> intent.putExtras(param);

The data of bitmap nerver appear in the encoded uri :

> String uri = **intent.toUri(URI_INTENT_SCHEME)**;
>
> (uri) ->
>   intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;launchFlags=0x10000000;component=com.xxxx.xxx/.activity.xxxx;end

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array extras are not supported in `Intent.toUri()`. Only the following types are supported (this is taken from the source code for `Intent.toUri()`:

```
            char entryType =
                    value instanceof String    ? 'S' :
                    value instanceof Boolean   ? 'B' :
                    value instanceof Byte      ? 'b' :
                    value instanceof Character ? 'c' :
                    value instanceof Double    ? 'd' :
                    value instanceof Float     ? 'f' :
                    value instanceof Integer   ? 'i' :
                    value instanceof Long      ? 'l' :
                    value instanceof Short     ? 's' :
                    '\0';
```